# Runtime Error when trying to Loop Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

Met with Runtime Error 1004 but can't figure out whats wrong.

It works when I click run on the XD1111X sheet but doesn't loop to another sheet or work when click run in another sheet. Would appreciate any advice..

```
    Sub LoopWorksheetsAndRunVBA()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Loop through specified worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("XD1111X", "XD2222X", "XD3333X"))
        
        Activate a cell in each worksheet
        ws.Range("A1").Activate
        
        Call EachVeh(ws)
        
    Next ws

    End Sub

    Sub EachVeh(ws As Worksheet)

    wsName = ActiveSheet.Name

    Dim varResponse As Variant
    varResponse = MsgBox("Clear data?", vbYesNo, "CAUTION")
    If varResponse \<\> vbYes Then Exit Sub
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Range("A2:F1000").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Dim rng As Range, destRow As Long
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range '-- this is used to store the single cell in the For Each loop

    Set shtSrc = Sheets("CALCULATE")
    Set shtDest = Sheets(wsName)

    destRow = 2 'Start copying to this row on destination sheet

' Set range to search for v
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("A1:A5000"), shtSrc.UsedRange)

    For Each c In rng.Cells
    If (c.Value = wsName) Then
    c.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 7).Copy \_
    shtDest.Cells(destRow, 1) 'Copy a 7 cell wide block to the other sheet, paste into Column on row    destRow
    destRow = destRow + 1
    End If
    Next

    End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy To Multiple Worksheets

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LoopWorksheetsAndRunVBA()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("XD1111X", "XD2222X", "XD3333X"))
        EachVeh ws
    Next ws

End Sub

Sub EachVeh(ByVal dws As Worksheet)

    Dim Response As Long: Response = MsgBox("Clear data?", vbYesNo, "CAUTION")
    If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = dws.Parent.Sheets("CALCULATE")
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = Intersect(sws.Range("A1:A5000"), sws.UsedRange)
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("A2")
    Dim dName As String: dName = dws.Name
    dws.Range("A2:F1000").ClearContents

    Dim sCell As Range

    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        If StrComp(CStr(sCell.Value), dName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            sCell.Resize(, 7).Copy dfCell
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next sCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems like the issue is with the line wsName = ActiveSheet.Name. This line is referring to the active sheet, but the code is trying to loop through multiple worksheets, so the active sheet may not always be the one that is currently being processed.Maybe replace wsName = ActiveSheet.Name with wsName = ws.Name in the EachVeh sub.

Also, make sure that the worksheets listed in the For Each loop exist in the workbook. If any of the worksheets are missing, it can cause a runtime error.